# Hadoop use only master node for processing data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've setup a Hadoop 2.5 cluster with 1 master node(namenode and secondary namenode and datanode) and 2 slave nodes(datanode).All of the machines use Linux CentOS 7 - 64bit. When I run my MapReduce program (wordcount), I can only see that master node is using extra CPU and RAM. Slave nodes are not doing a thing.

I've checked the logs from all of the namenode and there is nothing wrong on slave nodes. Resource Manager is running and all of the slave nodes can see the Resource Manager.
Datanodes are working in terms of distributed data storing but I can't see any indication of distributed data processing. Do I have to configure the xml configuration files in some other way so all of the machines will process data while I'm running my MapReduce Job?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are mentioaning the IP's Addresses of the daanodes on the Masternode networking files. Also each node in the cluster is supposed to contain IP address of the other machines.
Besides that check the includes file if it contains the relevant datanodes entry onto it or not.