# Only master node working on 4-node cluster using Hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to set up and use a 4-node Hadoop cluster. 
Setting up seems to go fine, as everything is running in the master and slave nodes.

Master: DataNode, ResourceManager, SecondaryNameNode, NameNode, NodeManager

Slaves: NodeManager, DataNode

Also, the logs show no errors. When I try to run my code however, it takes roughly the same amount of time as when I run it on a single node. Also, there is no increased CPU activity on any of the slave nodes.

Slaves can ssh to the master node, master node is listening at the correct port, ...

Any help on how I can track down the problem?

Thanks!

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2
Hadoop version: 2.6.0

I have seen related questions, but they were no help to me:

[hadoop cluster is using only master node or all nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028288/hadoop-cluster-is-using-only-master-node-or-all-nodes)

[Hadoop use only master node for processing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945312/hadoop-use-only-master-node-for-processing-data)

Comment: Have you installed Hadoop cluster using Ambari?

Comment: No I have not. According to http://ambari.apache.org/ they do not support 64-bit Ubuntu 14. I can't change OS.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have only one datanode and two nodemangers. It not much great configuration compared to single node cluster. To check whats happen you can goto resource manager UI . By default its on port 8088.